# Libgdx | Viewport update method not working as expected

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport

I am currently working on a top-down game. It is now time for me to implement a minimap, and I am having trouble doing so. There's 1 viewport and camera for the player/world, another viewport/camera for the hud. What I tried to do was create another viewport/camera the size of the world for the minimap and then draw every thing I want to show on the map (The tiledmap) with a batch, setting the projection matrix to the minimapcamera.combined. It works, except for when I try to make the viewport smaller. Obvisously it can't be as big as the screen :

```
float ratio = (float) width / (float) height;
    float scaledHeight = width / ratio;

    joystick.getViewport().update(width, (int) scaledHeight);
    System.out.println("RESIZED : " + width + " : " + height);
    miniMapViewport.update(width / 8, (int) scaledHeight / 8);
```

This code is in the resize method. The joystick also has it's own viewport. Now, the problem is that for some reason, updating the minimap viewport to width/8 and scaledHeight/8 also shrinks everything else in the window, as if it's effecting all the viewports. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, it's not correct to change the width and height of a viewport using its update method unless you've subclassed Viewport to behave differently. All of Libgdx's built-in Viewports are designed for various strategies that fill the screen in one way or another, so for a minimap, you either need to subclass Viewport or directly call `Gdx.gl.glViewport` yourself. As for why changing one of them changes all of them, you are doing something wrong in your render method, but you didn't show that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Do I even need a viewport for the minimap? I don't see what could be wrong in my render method.

Comment: There are many different ways it could be done, with and without using a viewport. And it also depends on what you are actually putting in the minimap (exact duplicate of game world zoomed out, or a simplified map version of the world, does it show fog of war, does it show the entire map  at once or a cropped subset of it, etc.). But I do think for almost any type of minimap it is far easier with a separate camera, which can be used either with a viewport or a FrameBuffer. You would get much better help on the Libgdx forum than on this site because this is so open ended.

Comment: Maybe take a look at my new thread : http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=22760

Comment: @Tenfour04 It would help greatly